# Failing in salt-api

Tags: salt-stack

Team,

I'm facing difficulties setting up salt-api.

I'm in a setup ubuntu 16 and CherryPy 3.5. Which is a open bug https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37783 .

I managed to downgrade to CherryPy 3.2.3.

```
rest_cherrypy:      
    port: 8000      
    disable_ssl: True


external_auth:   pam:
    saltuser:
      - .*
```

Upon salt-api and salt-master restart

curl -k http://localhost:8000

```
{"clients": ["local", "local_async",
> "local_batch", "local_subset", "runner", "runner_async", "ssh",
> "wheel", "wheel_async"], "return": "Welcome"}
```

While login or submitting a job I get **401 Unauthorized** .

curl -sSk http://localhost:8000/login -H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' -d username=saltuser -d password=passwd -d eauth=pam

curl -vki  http://localhost:8000   -H "Accept: application/x-yaml"   -d client=local -d tgt='stg-ubuntu102*'  -d fun='cmd.run' -d "kwarg": {"cmd": "touch /tmp/mannoj"}

Can someone please guide me here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute commands through the Salt API you need either to login while executing the command or passing `X-Auth-Token`. So what you need to do is to use the token that was generated by executing the login command

First make sure that you have a system user before executing the following

```
curl -sSk http://localhost:8000/login -H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' -d username=saltuser -d password=passwd -d eauth=pam
```

In your next request:

```
curl -vki http://localhost:8000 -H "Accept: application/x-yaml" -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN_GOES_HERE" -d client=local -d tgt='stg-ubuntu102*' -d fun='cmd.run' -d "kwarg": {"cmd": "touch /tmp/mannoj"}
```

> Note that I have added `-H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN_GOES_HERE"`

For more information check the [following page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#authentication)

Comment: 401 Unauthorized
Could not authenticate using provided credentials

Comment: I have updated the answer again, do you have a system user called saltuser ?

Comment: salt user exists in system. Now token is generated. While calling job using "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN_GOES_HERE". It says         <h2>401 Unauthorized</h2>
        <p>No permission -- see authorization schemes</p>

Comment: curl -vki http://localhost:8000 -H "Accept: application/x-yaml" -H "X-Auth-Token:8edb1bfe0a1e8zadbe369fda7b4e70322324b03ff76b27445gc68ad47a1796u7" -d client=local -d tgt='stg-ubuntu*' -d fun='test.ping' -d arg , Is the curl call.

Comment: Coulld you try to upgrade cherrypy to the latest version 10.x  and try a new token again ?

Comment: I tried downgrading from 3.5 to 3.2 using curl -O https://codeload.github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/tar.gz/3.2.3 . Looks like they don't have any 10.2. And I tried since past 1 hr to see if any latest upgrade or install from https://pypi.org/project/CherryPy/#files is working. Looks like it won't install. It just breaks. Any pointers for new one?

Comment: leme install and get back to you.